Is it possible to directly prove such a tensor identity, rather than by an argument about how tensors transform?
This question is motivated by a physics (special relativity) related exercise, but I am focusing on a mathematical aspect of it here. I am asked to prove the following identity, assuming that $F^{\alpha\beta}$ is an antisymmetric tensor:

$$ F_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}{}_{,\nu}F^{\nu}{}_{\alpha} = -F_{\mu\alpha,\beta}F^{\alpha\beta} \tag{1}$$

Now, I think I've grasped the general idea of how to establish this identity, at least in the context of SR. Namely, since we can assume a flat metric, we choose coordinates in which $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu}$, so that the metric tensor is constant. Then, write the left hand side as follows:
\begin{align*}
F_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}{}_{,\nu}F^{\nu}{}_{\alpha} &= \left(\eta^{\lambda\alpha}   F_{\mu\lambda}\right)_{,\nu}\ \eta_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma}  && \text{Contract with metric to raise and lower indices}
\\&= \require{cancel}\cancel{\eta^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{,\nu}F_{\mu\lambda}\eta_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma}} +\eta^{\lambda\alpha}F_{\mu\lambda,\nu}\eta_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma} && \text{Chain rule, partial derivative of constant metric vanishes}
\\&= \delta^{\lambda}_{\sigma}F_{\mu\lambda,\nu}F^{\nu\sigma} && \eta^{\lambda\alpha}\eta_{\sigma\alpha}=\delta^\lambda_\sigma
\\&= F_{\mu\lambda,\nu}F^{\nu\lambda}
\\&= -F_{\mu\lambda,\nu}F^{\lambda\nu} && \text{Use antisymmetry of } F
\\&= -F_{\mu\alpha,\beta}F^{\alpha\beta} && \text{Rewrite summation indices: } \lambda \leftrightarrow \alpha, \nu\leftrightarrow\beta
\end{align*}
So, now we've established the identity in this choice of coordinates, the argument we often give in the context of physics (and probably not only), is that a tensor identity that holds in one "frame" (coordinate system) will hold in any frame, because a coordinate transformation means transforming the components of tensors by the Jacobian. Since both sides of the identity constitute tensors that transform by exactly this same way then, the equality will hold good in all other choices of coordinates.
Now I come to my question which is, is there a more direct way to demonstrate that this equality holds in general coordinates?
What I got so far in attempting to do this, i.e not picking special coordinates, so that the partial derivative of the metric doesn't necessarily vanish:
\begin{align*}
F_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}{}_{,\nu}F^{\nu}{}_{\alpha} &= \left(g^{\lambda\alpha} F_{\mu\lambda}\right)_{,\nu}\ g_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma} 
\\&= g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{,\nu}F_{\mu\lambda}g_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma} +g^{\lambda\alpha}F_{\mu\lambda,\nu}g_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma}
\\&= g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{,\nu}g_{\sigma\alpha}F_{\mu\lambda}F^{\nu\sigma} +\delta^{\lambda}_{\sigma}F_{\mu\lambda,\nu}F^{\nu\sigma}
\\&= g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{,\nu}g_{\sigma\alpha}F_{\mu\lambda}F^{\nu\sigma} +F_{\mu\lambda,\nu}F^{\nu\lambda}
\\&= \underbrace{g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{,\nu}g_{\sigma\alpha}F_{\mu\lambda}F^{\nu\sigma}}_{\large\stackrel{?}{=}0} -F_{\mu\alpha,\beta}F^{\alpha\beta} 
\end{align*}
It seems that for this identity to indeed hold true, the indicated expression should vanish identically. However, nothing I did so far allowed me to demonstrate this. I've inserted the Christoffel symbols of the first kind, checked various symmetries, etc. but nothing seems to help. I've even tried to subject this expression to symbolic manipulation software to see whether it can give some new insight, and perhaps it can but I am not yet proficient enough at using such tools.
It would be great to see a direct proof of this, as I feel it would help bridge what I take as a more "physical" understanding (argument about how tensors transform) with a more rigorous approach to such a proof.
Edit: an additional point to consider/clarify here is whether either side of the alleged identity are even tensors to begin with. It is not clear that they transform as such, due to the partial derivative involved. Perhaps the exercise was just poor in explaining that point, but is it that as long as we have partial derivatives like this we must assume that such an identity can hold only given a constant metric, and when we go to any curvilinear coordinates, whether in flat spacetime or not, we must "switch" $\partial \rightarrow \nabla$? (of course, for a constant metric we may write, "conceptually" that $\nabla=\partial$, if I am not wrong).

You should be using covariant derivatives. Then, metric compatibility of the Levi-Civita connection should save the day.

@peek-a-boo Thanks, I did go with this direction for a bit.. what I seem to get from $g^{\lambda\alpha}{}{;\nu} = 0$ is: $$g^{\lambda\alpha}{}{,\nu}=  -\Gamma^{\lambda}{}{\rho\nu}g^{\rho\alpha}-\Gamma^{\alpha}{}{\nu\rho}g^{\lambda\rho} $$ but on further reflection, it seems like it can't be enough.. because if we are to use the assumption of flat spacetime somehow, this isn't embedded in $g^{\lambda\alpha}{}_{;\nu} = 0$, which holds even in curved spacetime (which is the metric compatibility you mention in fact, if I am not wrong).

@peek-a-boo -- I think I understand what you mean better now, see edit. But if that's all there is to it, I find it a bit weird this exercise asked to prove a tensor identity while using a manifestly non-tensorial expression due to the partial derivative. Perhaps it is just an error/sloppiness of this exercise... I'm not 100% sure yet, maybe I'm missing something else here.

Im saying that your problem statement only makes sense if you use coordinates in which the metric components are constant. The general way of formulating the problem should use covariant derivatives from the beginning (then as a special case in which metric components are constant, you get the above ‘simplification’ of covariant derivatives to partial derivatives).

@peek-a-boo Got it, thank you

If you write such an identity in flat space in a global constant system of coordinates, already introducing curvilinear coordinates yields a quite different expression.
The transformation rule for partial derivatives of a tensor is "comma goes to semicolon", i.e. partial derivatives have to be replaced by covariant derivatives including the Christoffel terms, that represent the covariant derivative of the basis vectors $${\partial_i}_{;k} = \Gamma^s_{i,k} \partial_s$$ in
$$D_k (u^i e_i)  = (\partial_k u^i) \ e_i \ + \ u^i (D_k \ e_i) = u^i_{,k}\ e_i + u^i\  \Gamma^s_{i,k} e_s  $$
Covariant derivatives of tensors are tensors. Each index corresponds to a basis vector or 1-form in the tensor basis products. In contrast partial derivatives are a tool of differentiation and integration only and have no coordinate invariant, basis independent meaning.
